# Store Facebook avatar in MongoDB using Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to build my first Meteor app following the tutorial on the official site.
I use the `accounts-ui` and the `accounts-facebook` packages.

When a new user logins I want to store his avatar in the database.

What I have done so far:

```
// Insert a task into the collection

  Tasks.insert({

    text: text,

    createdAt: new Date(), // current time

    owner: Meteor.userId(),           // _id of logged in user

    username: Meteor.user().username || Meteor.user().profile.name , // username of logged in user

    avatar: Meteor.user().profile.picture

  });
```

And in HTML:

```
<template name="task">

  <li class="{{#if checked}}checked{{/if}}">
    <button class="delete">&times;</button>
    <img class="avatar" src="{{avatar}}">
    <input type="checkbox" checked="{{checked}}" class="toggle-checked" />
    <span class="text"><strong>{{username}}</strong></span>
    <span class="text">{{text}}</span>

  </li>

</template>
```

**If the user logins with Facebook everything is fine**, but if he tries to login with a custom user name I get the error:

```
Meteor.user(...).profile is undefined
```

**What I want to achieve :**

```
avatar: Meteor.user().profile.picture // if the user has a Facebook account
```

OR

```
avatar: "img/default" // if the user uses custom username
```

I already tried:

```
avatar: Meteor.user().profile.picture || avatar: "img/default"
```

But it does not work.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@kostenko you should read more about how to access object properties in javascript.

and here is the solution from your last try it was close:

```
var user = Meteor.user();
avatar: user && user.profile && user.profile.picture || "img/default";
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. For the record I found another solution but it is not as elegant so I m accepting yours. `try {
    defaultPic=Meteor.user().profile.picture;
          }
      catch(err) {
    defaultPic="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-person-128.png";
      }` and in insert    `avatar: defaultPic`